# Django doesn't show yellow page

Tags: django

So I have initialized a django project (v4.2.5) and every thing works fine and debug is set to True, but I never get the yellow page when errors occur, instead I always get this:

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

I do have

```
django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware
```

and `DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` is set to `true` as well

and I have to check what is the problem in terminal all the time, any idea what could be the problem?

Update:
my middlewares:

```
['debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.admindocs.middleware.XViewMiddleware']
```

Comment: Can you show your `settings.py` variable `MIDDLEWARE` ?

Comment: @ArunT i added the used `middlewares` in order

Comment: I see that you have added the DebugToolBar, Does removing it having any effect? 
Was it working before you added DebugToolBar?

Comment: @ArunT answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem was `DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` just remove that setting which defaults to `False` and gets fixed.